# Use of enum with INSTANCE

Tags: java, groovy, enums

I come across a piece of Groovy code for a Cassandra Client and my efforts to find any relevant information about this pattern and would appreciate some explanation of the use of an enum for this and what the INSTANCE keyword does.

```
enum CassandraClient {
INSTANCE

Cluster cluster
Session session
CQLDataLoader cqlDataLoader
String contactPoint = "contactPoint"
String username = "username"
String password = "password"

private CassandraClient() {
    cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(contactPoint).withCredentials(username, password).build()
    session = cluster.connect()
    cqlDataLoader = new CQLDataLoader(session)
}
}
```

Comment: Looks like a singleton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an implementation of the singleton pattern. Actually accoring to "Effective Java" by Joshua Block (a very good book) it is the best way to implement a singleton this way.

`INSTANCE` is the actual single enum element that is the singleton instance.